# Decode SAMLResponse in XML or in readable format

Tags: php, single-sign-on, cakephp-3.0, saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to integrate Okta SAML SSO in my web application.
After creation of application via development account, once i call the generated url from broswer,
it redirects to my web app with some `SAMLResponse`.

that `SAMLResponse` is not readable format, i have tried to decode it via base64_decode() function, but it not returns XML code.

basically i need to get some details from that XML as well.

I am using cakephp 3.4 for integration of SAML SSO using okta.

any suggestion for that ?

i have tried to decode it via base64_decode() function, but it not returns XML code.

in some sites it shows, we need to decode it via base64 and it returns XML data.

i have tried some online decoders where it decodes that response to xml and returns data properly.
i have checked that response is valid via firefox plugin named 'SAML tracer'.

[image: Image of response which I got from Okta]

Comment: [perhaps this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466641/how-to-verify-a-saml-signature-for-http-redirect-binding/41469795#41469795) will be of use